# How to control my aggressive puppy

Tags: dogs, aggression

My pup who is around 4 months old is very aggressive and hostile to his mother and other dogs in general. He often barks at dogs 3-4 times his size (the mom's no exception).

Such aggressiveness in him often forces us to chain him for extended periods of time should he escape and hurt himself in doggie turf wars. I myself am no fond of chaining the dog but it seems a necessary evil. What are some good and humane alternatives to chaining my dog for extended periods of time

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to train a dog is rewarding him when he shows behaviour we like and punish him when he show behaviour we dislike.

Don't use the chain it will only make the pup frustrated instead, take the weekend off so you have a day or 2 :

Watch the puppy's behaviour, from the moment he acts aggressive towards the mother punish him by gently taking him and placing him in apart from the rest of the dogs (or the mother in your case). After a couple of minutes bring him back, in the beginning he will keep doing this, keep putting him apart from the rest and add a minute to his punishing time, from the moment he gets tired of being aggressive reward him with some treats and by acting very enthusiastic. You'll see after a while he'll understand that this behavior gets him places instead of getting punished.